# Is there anyway that ConEmu can display local bash and remote ssh on the same tab?

Tags: ssh, conemu, git-bash

- **OS:** Win 10
- **ConEmu:** 180626 [64]

I would like to display a ssh to my remote server and a local bash on the same. I can easily split with CTRL+SHIFT+ (e or o) but if I'm on remote it opens another remote panel and similarly opens another local if I'm on local. I've tried setting up two tasks and then a third to call each of them but no joy, has any one setup this on their ConEmu?

My tasks are:

**Remote**

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "ssh ubuntu@address.com -i c:/Work/application-files/key.pem" -new_console:t:"address.com":P:"<PowerShell>"
```

**Local**

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -new_console:t:"repos Bash"
```

Comment: You have interface, what's the problem? https://conemu.github.io/en/LaunchNewTab.html

Comment: I'm opening up multiple shells with different combinations many times a day so a shortcut opening all the shells I need in one go is great. If that's not what you're referring to please clarify.

Comment: @Maximus just spotted you're the Author of ConEmu! Thanks a million for an amazing terminal! :)

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of messing here's my solution. This ConEmu task will open and split vertically a local bash and ssh remote to a specified dir. I hope it helps someone else.

**Windows** all the way

```
> -cur_console:d:C:\Work\repos -cur_console:t:"repos Bash" -cur_console:C:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\git.ico" "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i

-cur_console:ns1T50V -cur_console:d:C:\Work\repos -cur_console:t:"m6 address.com":P:"<PowerShell>" -cur_console:C:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\git.ico" ssh ubuntu@address.com -i c:/Work/application-files/key.pem -t "cd node/mynewapp/; bash --login" -cur_console:ns1T50V
```

In a **WSL** setup you'll need to make some adjustments:

```
-cur_console:f -cur_console:d:C:\Users\Spider-Man -cur_console:t:"repos Bash" "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -c "cd /home/Spider-Man/repos && bash"

-cur_console:fns1T50V:f -cur_console:d:C:\Users\Spider-Man -cur_console:t:"ssh beta server":P:"<PowerShell>" "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -c "ssh ubuntu@address.net -i /home/Spider-Man/repos/keys/address.net  -t 'cd node/app/ && bash'"
```